# PrimeNG modal p-dialog not scrollable

Tags: angular, primeng

I previously submitted an [issue](https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/issues/2902) about this, but maybe I am just missing something, so here is my problem:

I have a screen-overflowing data table, from which I select items, which pop up as modal dialogs. Unfortunately I cannot get scrolling to work on the p-dialog.

Doing `<p-dialog  [style]="{'margin':'80px', 'overflow':'scroll'}">` only creates a horizontal scroller on the modal dialog for some reason.

And to make things worse, the scrolling still works on the background, which I want to be static.

How do I create scrolling (vertical too!) on a p-dialog and focus on it, disabling simultaneous scrolling of the background?

See also plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/6H0Q2Cm0184pLw3bto1h?p=preview

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should apply scrolling to the `p-dialog` and not for the `ul` tag as below,

```
p-dialog .ui-dialog {
  overflow: scroll;
  max-height: 70%;
}
```

**Reason**: `p-dialog` contains a div which contains another div with classes `ui-dialog-content` whose default overflow property is auto. So to override it you need to set at the root level. Follow the below plunker.

**Note**:

- Use `%` to preseve responsiveness
- Also use `max-height` property to set a maximum height of the modal beyond which the scroll bar appears

To hide the background you should be using as below,

```
<div [class.hide]="showDialog">
<p-dataTable [paginator]="false" [value]="data">
  <p-column header="Data">
    <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-rowData="rowData">{{rowData}}</ng-template>
  </p-column>
</p-dataTable>
</div>
```

Add a class `.hide` as below,

```
.hide{
  opacity :0;
}
```

Updated **[LIVE DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/cEphNASE0WH00lEdtAOF?p=preview)**

Comment: Thank you very much. Do you perhaps know how to disable the background scrolling when dialog scrolling is active? My approach would be moving <body> from index.html into a component and using ngstyle/ngclass on it, but this seems rather hacky and unintuitive and manipulates a big part of the program to fix a small feature.

Answer (score 6):

Using primeng v. 7.0.3

For me this did the trick about having overflow dialog content (a p-listbox inside the dialog) display with vertical scrollbar:

```html
<p-dialog [contentStyle]="{'overflow-y': 'auto', 'overflow-x': 'hidden', 
                           'max-height': '80vh','min-height':'250px'}">
</p-dialog>
```

Just tweaking `max-height` can get the dialog header and footer to always display (header with title, and footer with action buttons: Select, Cancel), while the dialog content was scrollable.

Comment: This one is useful to add scrollbar to p-dialog

Comment: For the p-sidebar, adding `[style]={'overflow-y': 'auto'}"` to the element also fixes the issue on v6.0.0

Comment: Had to use this inline `[contentStyle]` attribute answer because scoped CSS wasn't working. Maybe the CSS in gloabl styles.scss file would have worked?  Either way it fixed the issue with broken primeNg elements.

Answer (score 2):

You should set the min-height and max-height. Use absolute values, not percentages...

```
.ui-dialog-content {
    max-height: 500px;
    min-height: 200px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
    padding: 15px;
}
```

For disabling background scroll, set:

```
<body [ngClass]="'<class for overflow: hidden>': isMyDialogVisible" ...>
```

where you set isMyDialogVisible to true while the dialog is being displayed.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But in the meanwhile, we switched from prime-ng to ag-grid and built a ui-library for components like a modal dialog. That specific ui-modal element that I built sets `overflow: hidden` on <body> when the component initilizes and `overflow: ''` ondestroy

Comment: We also switched for one component or another to a different plugin :(
Sometimes a PrimeNg update crashes a component (like the upload component), and some PrimeNg components don't work at all as expected.
I will stick to material design and disencourage using PrimeNg for the next projects - although I was really pleased with prime until this project...